Deployed smart contract on TRON not showing code tabs and transaction is missing from list
I have deployed a simple smart contract to try on the TRON Shasta network via
tronide. 
Here is the simple contract address:
contract.
I assumed it would display code tabs on the smart contract explorer. However, it only displays contracts published instead of code. Maybe it is because the contract is unverified? How to verify the contract on TRON?

Also, the weird thing is I tried to execute the function inside tronide and via script.
The result on tronide is recorded in the transaction list and updated in the contract state (tx hash). But via a script, it is not recorded and does not update the contract state. However, the tx hash status is successful (tx hash)
For better context, this is the script that I use to interact via tronweb:
const store = async (tronWeb: TronWeb) => {
  const store = await tronWeb.transactionBuilder.triggerSmartContract(
    "TQmchUxiLsztmXybCALn5KT2EBA3SPe1HA",
    "store(uint256)",
    {
      feeLimit: 100000000,
      callValue: 0,
    },
    [
      {
        type: "uint256",
        value: BigInt(69),
      },
    ]
  );

  // sign transaction
  const signedTx = await tronWeb.trx.sign(store.transaction);
  const broadcastTx = await tronWeb.trx.sendRawTransaction(signedTx);

  console.log("broadcastTx: ", broadcastTx);
};

Any solution to resolve this issue?
